# Some links not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

My site is working on all major browsers, but I see a problem with some links on Chrome.

At the top menu ('Início Portfólio Sobre Contato') all is ok. Below that there is another navigation area where some words are links to specific jobs, but when I click them it doesn't work. That's occurring with the thumb images below that area (and the diagonal line).

It's curious because some links are working (in the main navigation) and others aren't.

My website is: http://www.santosidaniel.com

Does someone know what the problem is? I'm on Mac OS, with the latest Chrome.

Comment: usually people post some code here to help us. é boa prática adicionar o código aqui.  :)

Comment: all links worked fine for me. qual está dando problema?

Comment: For me the links don't work, as you said, but as soon as I open Developer Tools on Chrome it starts working and correctly moving to the pointed objects. When I close the Developer Tools again, the links stop working again.

Comment: I've not posted the code because I don't know in which of all JS, HTML part and CSS may be the problem.

Comment: RASG, the links related to the nav "thumbs_menu" and article: "words_menu" aren't working

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what the others says, but I see this code in your page:

```
$('#main_menu a').bind('click',function(event){
    if(!$(this).parent('li').hasClass('lang') && !$(this).parent('li').hasClass('langlast')) {
        $(document).find('title').text($(this).text() + ' | santosidaniel');

        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Which seems to be the effective code that cause the scrolling, at least in Chrome. The other links doesn't work because they didn't have the function binded?

If I adds `#words_menu a` and `#thumbs_menu a` too, then the links will work.

Obviously this doesn't explain why it does work in other browsers, but this seems to solve the problem, at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Editing this due to new information,

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

It looks like the library you're using requires using appropriate syntax to move horizontally through each section through your thumbnails.

Try setting up JS statements like

`$(...).scrollTo( '520px', 800 );`

Comment: But as you could see are working in all other browsers. And none of all the links are with a incorrect id or spelling. And the `.scrollcontainer` part aren't the part of the code in charge to make the links movement.

Comment: It sounds like it's a problem with the javascript library you're using. Did you write it yourself or is it from somewhere? That might help to diagnose this.

Comment: There are many librarys there, only two of them have been writed to me (but not by myself): slider.js and contact.js. I think that problem may be related to the slider.js

Comment: Ajkochanowicz, but my code is only with percentage, this will not be apropriate :(

Comment: Read the docs! Percentages are supported: $(...).scrollTo( '50%', 800 );

Comment: Seeing what you said the difference is that in the code it works calling the "slide" element, so, the code makes the correct calculation and I don't need to set in pixels
`$(container).stop().scrollTo($(slide), 800);`

Comment: So you fixed it? I don't understand.

Comment: My brother will try to solve to me, if he find the solution I will be back to say (he is a programmer, but unavailable all the time, because of this I asked you) Thank you so much your time and help, but of course, if you find a good way I will be happy too :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be something in your javascript, if I disable javascript, the anchors do work. Your javascript is all minned so it's hard to tell what's happening, but my money is on the `jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js` script.

Comment: The `scrollTo` is as I've downloaded. May be a incompatibility? How to have the same function without that problem if is a incompatibility?

Comment: It is as you've downloaded, but you'll need to use it properly per http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Sorry ajkochanowicz but I don't know how to use properly if isn't like this. As I said, I'm a beginner :)

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what exactly it is that's happening, you could be attaching the event listener wrong, some other bit of script could be conflicting with it, etc. etc.

Comment: You might start by not including that script and see if that is in fact the source of the problem. If so, it's debugging time, or scrap the plugin and just have the browser do its thing. You'll lose the effect, but your page won't be broken.

Comment: But when have a conflict appear an error at Firebug. And that event listener seems to be right.

Comment: Well, clearly something's not working the way you want it to.

Comment: ajkochanowicz when I set to percentage if I add another project I will need to recalculate again which is the correct percentage, with that code I don't need to do this, the code make it to me

Comment: Surely, if you disable the javascript the anchor will work, but, not the smooth scroll effect.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why, but if you change this line:

*slider.js (line 67)*

```
$('body').stop().scrollTo(container, 800);
```

by this

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: container.offset().top
}, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
```

Will solve the problem.

Comment: Hey guys, seems to have a problem not perceived now, the main menu now is not working and the others one are working. Someone know now what may be the problem?